# Issue importing Google Neuroglancer Package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Google's Neuroglancer which I downloaded from GitHub and trying to run an example script provided by them. However, one of the lines is `import neuroglancer`, and since I cloned the whole repo there is a neuroglancer folder with all of the required files, but I am getting the following error:

> ImportError: No module named 'neuroglancer'

Is there any way I could fix this? I don't see the issue since neuroglancer is in the same file path as the python script.

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as more information on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are running the example in the neuroglancer project try following their [guide](https://github.com/google/neuroglancer/tree/master/examples/dependent-project).

Otherwise you might want to try and installing the Neuroglancer package using something like pip and a virtual environment to be able to import the package into the project.